# The signature is invalid - Magento 2 Oauth 1 Rest API Authentication

Tags: magento2, rest-api, oauth

I need to generate access token for third party extension in Magento. 
I create integration, now I should sent request to **/oauth/token/request** in order to get a request token, but I get following error:

**oauth_problem=The+signatire+is+invalid.+Verify+and+try+again.**

My signature function is as follow

```
function sign($method, $url, $data, $consumerSecret, $tokenSecret)
{

    $array=[

        $method,
        $url,
        $data['oauth_nonce'],
        $data['oauth_signature_method'],
        $data['oauth_timestamp'],
        $data['oauth_version'],
        $data['oauth_consumer_key'],
        $tokenSecret,

    ];

    $url = urlEncodeAsZend($url);
    $data = urlEncodeAsZend(http_build_query($array, '', '&'));
    $data = implode('&', $array);
    $secret = implode('&', [$consumerSecret, $tokenSecret]);

    return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $data, $secret, true));
}

function urlEncodeAsZend($value)
{
    $encoded = rawurlencode($value);
    $encoded = str_replace('%7E', '~', $encoded);
    return $encoded;
}
```

PS: my oauth_token is empty because in this step no token is created in Integrations.Doc says :

*To generate the signature, you must use the HMAC-SHA1 signature method. The signing key is the concatenated values of the consumer secret and token secret separated by the ampersand (&) character (ASCII code 38), **even if empty**.*

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html

I am using **Magento 2.3**

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is Magento's bug.

You can refer to this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19159?fbclid=IwAR3D_BJokrXw8qP7cDOOjhF7r3uBSe50D31ej7qWXopQdIPwHqf9OW4PMsc